# WebSocket connection to 'ws//..' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-websocket, tomcat9

I'm using Spring Websocket as in the following :

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-websockets

everything is working properly and messages are sent if I use 8080 port , However when I use port 80 I get the exception in title in console.log from browser . I have tried 3 different servers with the same issue on port 80 using Tomcat. any ideas ?

Comment: Port 80 is the default port for most http application. The chances are very high that an application is using the port on your servers. Try the lsof -i :80 command to see what application is listening on the port 80.

Comment: I tried it on the 3 servers and I didnt get any output,  as tomcat already using port 80 I don't think there will be another application listening on that port